# VBA Referencing named cells

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table where some cells are grayed out. I want to write a code that will automatically turn a cell white when clicked on, and stay that way if something is typed in. If nothing is typed in, it will return back to gray. Currently I have:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

            Dim Temp As Range                
            If Range(“Temp”).Value = "" Then
            Range("Temp").Interior.Pattern = xlGray25


            'If the cell is gray, it turns it white when clicked on. This part works fine
            If Target.Interior.Pattern = xlGray25 Then
            Target.Interior.Pattern = xlSolid
            ‘Labels the changed cell as “Temp” so it can be referenced
            ThisWorkbook.Names.Add “Temp”, Target

 End If
End Sub
```

However, the

```
If Range("Temp").Value = "" Then
```

line gets a mismatch error. I tried it without the .value and setting "Temp" to a specific cell, but neither works. All the other sources I checked said that should be the correct way to reference a named cell. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: have you tried disabling events while inside the _SelectionChange block?

Comment: The Range object may refer to multiple cells. Are you talking about specific single cell or multiple ones? Rgds,

Comment: Would it not be more convenient to use Conditional Formatting for this purpose?

Comment: First, you're missing an End If statement.

Comment: Also Dim Temp As Range and Range(“Temp”) are two different ranges.  Try removing the quotes around the Temp and see if that helps.  Also, you'll have to set the range to be something.  As it stands now, you have a Temp variable that is expecting a Range, but you're not setting the range.

Comment: Alex Bell - "Temp" only refers to a single cell at a time.  Aiken - Conditional Formatting does not change the color when it is clicked, only when a value is entered.  Julien Marrec - Haha sorry, you are correct but the code still doesn't work regardless.  sous2817 - I tried removing the quotes and setting the range, but neither work. Thanks for your suggestions though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you use a module-level variable to keep track of the previous selection.

```
Private mrPrevious As Range

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Not mrPrevious Is Nothing Then
        'If IsEmpty(mrPrevious.Value) Then
        If IsEmpty(mrPrevious.Cells(1).Value) Then
            mrPrevious.Interior.Pattern = xlGray25
        End If
    End If

    If Target.Interior.Pattern = xlGray25 Then
        Target.Interior.Pattern = xlSolid
    End If

    Set mrPrevious = Target

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. However, I tried using the code and it will turn gray cells to white when I click on them, but it won't turn them back to gray when nothing is inputted.

Comment: It works for me. Click on a cell and it turns white. Click off the cell without entering and it turns back gray. Enter something and it stays white. Delete the entry, click another cell, and it turns gray.

Comment: Okay yes, normally it should work (thank you!!) but unfortunately I am dealing with merged cells (big nono, I know, but I cannot change the format). Is there a way to make this applicable when the "mrPrevious" cell is a merged cell? Thank you so much for your help!!

Comment: I edited the post to only look at the first cell of mrPrevious. That way it will work with merged cells too. They are terrible, but sometimes you have no choice. Sorry I didn't consider that originally.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for VBA. Please read about "Conditional Formatting". It's in the Style group at the middle of the Home ribbon.